# How to transparently propagate an HTTP header via a RestTemplate call?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application deployed on a Tomcat server receiving requests and making some other HTTP REST requests to other services using Spring `RestTemplate`.

```
client --> myApplication --> anotherService
```

In the incoming requests there is a `CORRELATION_ID` HTTP header, tracking the request.
I want any requests made to other services to have this header as well, so that I can correlate logs on the different servers.

How can I accomplish that without altering the existing code?

Is there any `RestTemplateInterceptor` I can set somewhere at the boot so that it intercepts any outgoing requests and adds that header? 
Or is there any way to intercept this event in the Tomcat server and propagate the header?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such automatic handling.

You can intercept the header on the incoming call and store it somewhere, in the request-context (a request scoped bean for instance).

You can then use a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` to put that into each out-going request. Add that interceptor with `restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(…)`

Comment: The first part would still be fine, but would it possible to avoid adding the interceptor to each part in the code where a new resttemplate is instantiated?

Comment: Hmm, I don’t think so. If you need that, you still have two easy options: Use your own `RestTemplate` factory, or expose the `RestTemplate` as a bean that you inject in your components.

Comment: I have a very similar problem, the only difference is that my outgoing request is not explicitly executed by me. I'm talking about an oAuth2 auth request towards an auth server (keycloak). I'm using keycloak spring boot adapter + spring security. Would you know if the keycloak adapter is using "under the hood" a RestTemplate to execute that auth request, because I need to add some extra headers to that request. Would this same strategy work here? Thanks.

Comment: I can only speculate on that, and my speculation would be that the global `RestTemplate` bean is not used, and that there is probably some other hook.